# how to deal with silex end of life for single page REST app

Tags: symfony, slim, lumen, silex

We have a large Silex/Angular app that is essentially a single page REST app.  We use Silex security throughout the PHP side.

With the end of life of Silex here, we're trying to figure out the best route to maintaining the app.  We're considering:

- Symfony
- Slim
- Lumen

Silex maintainers say to switch to Symfony, but we're concerned that it will require a lot of work to make it work for a single page app.

We've also considered Slim or Lumen - and of the two we're leaning more toward Slim since it seems to have a larger user base.

Any thoughts on a recommended way to go would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: without knowing anything about your app noone will be able to respond. my gut feeling still tells me to go with Symfony because Silex wasn't nothing else than a "stripped" Symfony anyway.

Comment: check https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8678 additionally

Comment: You could just fork Silex and maintain it yourself. Just cos Symfony ain't supporting it any more doesn't mean it'll suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Fabien Potencier, Silex has migrated to Symfony 4+. I work with Symfony since 2007 and it is one of the best PHP framework, in my opinion! I would like to encourage you to have a look at their documentation and also pay attention to its community. They are strong and also, they are up to date with the framework!

Comment: Thank you all for the advice!  Sounds like Symfony is the way to go.  :)